# Wrong number of dimensions: expected 0, got 1 with shape (1,)

Tags: theano, recurrent-neural-network, language-model

I am doing word-level language modelling with a vanilla rnn, I am able to train the model but for some weird reasons I am not able to get any samples/predictions from the model; here is the relevant part of the code:

```
train_set_x, train_set_y, voc = load_data(dataset, vocab, vocab_enc)  # just load all data as shared variables
index = T.lscalar('index')
x = T.fmatrix('x')
y = T.ivector('y')
n_x = len(vocab)
n_h = 100
n_y = len(vocab)

rnn = Rnn(input=x, input_dim=n_x, hidden_dim=n_h, output_dim=n_y)

cost = rnn.negative_log_likelihood(y)

updates = get_optimizer(optimizer, cost, rnn.params, learning_rate)

train_model = theano.function(
    inputs=[index],
    outputs=cost,
    givens={
        x: train_set_x[index],
        y: train_set_y[index]
    },
    updates=updates
)

predict_model = theano.function(
    inputs=[index],
    outputs=rnn.y,
    givens={
        x: voc[index]
    }
)

sampling_freq = 2
sample_length = 10
n_train_examples = train_set_x.get_value(borrow=True).shape[0]
train_cost = 0.
for i in xrange(n_train_examples):
    train_cost += train_model(i)
    train_cost /= n_train_examples

    if i % sampling_freq == 0:
       # sample from the model     
       seed = randint(0, len(vocab)-1)
       idxes = []
       for j in xrange(sample_length):
           p = predict_model(seed)
           seed = p
           idxes.append(p)
           # sample = ''.join(ix_to_words[ix] for ix in idxes)
           # print(sample)
```

I get the error: **"TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name "train.py:94"  at index 0(0-based)', 'Wrong number of dimensions: expected 0, got 1 with shape (1,).')"**

Now this corresponds to the following line (in the predict_model):

```
 givens={   x: voc[index]   }
```

Even after spending hours I am not able to comprehend how could there be a dimension mis-match when:

```
train_set_x has shape: (42, 4, 109)
voc has shape: (109, 1, 109)
```

And when I do train_set_x[index], I am getting *(4, 109)* which '**x**' Tensor of type fmatrix can hold (this is what happens in **train_model**) but when I do voc[index], I am getting *(1, 109)*, which is also a matrix but '**x**' cannot hold this, why ? !

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message refers to the definition of the whole Theano function named `predict_model`, not the specific line where the substitution with `givens` occurs.

The issue seems to be that `predict_model` gets called with an argument that is a *vector of length 1* instead of a *scalar*. The initial `seed` sampled from `randint` is actually a scalar, but I would guess that the output `p` of `predict_model(seed)` is a vector and not a scalar.

In that case, you could either return `rnn.y[0]` in `predict_model`, or replace `seed = p` with `seed = p[0]` in the loop over `j`.

Comment: You are right, the output of predict_model(seed) i.e rnn.y was a vector not a scalar. It was really dumb on my part :(, 
Thank you !